# Rendering video using WriteableBitmap causes choppy animation

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

So here's my setup:

- Camera images coming in at 1920x1080 @ 25 FPS
- Writing image data to `WriteableBitmap` on UI thread (simple copy, no processing)
- Two `Image` controls in two different windows on two different monitors has their `Source` property set to the `WriteableBitmap`
- Some generic UI stuff goes over the camera images

This works great, uses about 4% CPU on an old laptop (8 logical processors). The video is as smooth as can be. However, my UI has some animations (stuff moving around). When the camera display is running, those animations gets choppy.

Right now, the camera image is in Gray8 format, so it will be converted (I guess when calling `WritePixels`?). I also tried forcing one of the animations to 25 FPS too, no change.

Where should I start to resolve this? Is the issue that I'm locking the bitmap for too long, or is there something else going on? From what I can see locking the bitmap will cause the render thread to block, so moving that to another thread seems pointless. And it does feel like that somewhat defeats the purpose of `WriteableBitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is always going to be tricky because you're capturing at 25FPS whilst WPF tries to update at 60. It's difficult to offer any meaninful advice without seeing a testable project but I'd probably start by doing the updates in a [CompositionTarget.Rendering handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandf/archive/2007/10/09/fun-with-animation-part-1-compositiontarget-rendering.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean that I should do the animations manually in the `Rendering` event? I guess that would get them going at the same rate as the video.

Comment: No, I mean do your bitmap updates in the rendering handler. You know there'll be one render each time it's called, so updating your WriteableBitmaps in that function (at 25FPS, not every frame) might solve it.

Comment: Ah I see, that sounds reasonable. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I realize this is a couple of years old but I am in a similar situation and am wondering if this approach ended up working out for you -- or for any other advice you might have.  In my case I'm trying to display at a higher framerate